# I have a two dimensional array of chars and for some reason it will not let me compare a char inside the array to another char?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, char

```
public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Driver run = new Driver();
        run.it();

    }

    public void it() {

        Tester test = new Tester();
        test.fillBoard();
        test.placeQueens();
        test.printBoard();

    }

}

public class Tester {

    public char [][] board = new char [8][8];

    public void fillBoard() {

        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

            for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {

                board[i][j] =' ';

            }

        }

    }

    public boolean checkUp(int row , int col) {

        if (((row < 0) || (row > 7)) || ((col > 7) || (col < 0))) {

            if (board[row][col] == 'Q') {

                return false;

            } else {

                return checkUp(row - 1, col);

            }

        } else {

            return true;

        }

    }

    public boolean checkDown(int row , int col) {

        if (((row < 0) || (row > 7)) || ((col > 7) || (col < 0))) {

            if (board[row][col] == 'Q') {

                return false;

            } else {

                return checkDown(row + 1, col);

            }

        } else {

            return true;

        }

    }

    public boolean checkUpAndRight(int row , int col) {

        if (((row < 0) || (row > 7)) || ((col > 7) || (col < 0))) {

            if (board[row][col] == 'Q') {

                return false;

            } else {

                return checkUpAndRight(row - 1, col - 1);

            }

        } else {

            return true;

        }

    }

    public boolean checkDownAndRight(int row , int col) {

        if (((row < 0) || (row > 7)) || ((col < 0) || (col > 7))) {

            if (board[row][col] == 'Q') {

                return false;

            } else {

                return checkDownAndRight(row + 1, col - 1);

            }

        } else {

            return true;

        }

    }   

    public boolean checkUpAndLeft(int row, int col) {

        if (((row < 0) || (row > 7)) || ((col > 7) || (col < 0))) {

            if (board[row][col] == 'Q') {

                return false;

            } else {

                return checkUpAndLeft(row - 1, col + 1);

            }

        } else {

            return true;

        }

    }

    public boolean checkDownAndLeft(int row , int col) {

        if (((row < 0) || (row > 7)) || ((col > 7) || (col < 0))) {

            if (board[row][col] == 'Q') {

                return false;

            } else {

                return checkDownAndLeft(row + 1, col + 1);

            }

        } else {

            return true;

        }

    }

    public boolean checkLeft(int row , int col) {

        if (((row < 0) || (row > 7)) || ((col > 7) || (col < 0))) {

            if (board[row][col] == 'Q') {

                return false;

            } else {

                return checkLeft(row, col + 1);

            }

        } else {

            return true;

        }

    }

    public boolean checkRight(int row , int col) {

        if ((col > 7) || (col < 0)) {

            if (board[row][col] == 'Q') {

                return false;

            } else {

                return checkRight(row, col - 1);

            }

        } else {

            return true;

        }

    }

    public boolean checkSpot(int row, int col) {

        if ((checkUp(row, col) == true) && (checkDown(row, col) == true) && 
        (checkUpAndRight(row, col) == true) && (checkDownAndRight(row, col) == true) && 
        (checkUpAndLeft(row, col) == true) && (checkDownAndLeft(row, col) == true) && 
        (checkLeft(row, col) == true) && (checkRight(row, col) == true)) {

            return true;

        } else {

            return false;

        }

    }


    public void placeQueens() {


        for(int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {

            for(int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {

                if(checkSpot(row, col) == true) {

                    board[row][col] = 'Q';

                }

            }

        }

    }

    public void printBoard() {

        String rtn = "";
        String newRow = "+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+\n";
        rtn += newRow;
        rtn += "| "+ board[0][0] +" | "+ board[0][1] +" | "+ board[0][2] +" | "+ board[0][3] +" | "
        + board[0][4] +" | "+ board[0][5] +" | "+ board[0][6] +" | "+ board[0][7] +" |\n";
        rtn += newRow;
        rtn += "| "+ board[1][0] +" | "+ board[1][1] +" | "+ board[1][2] +" | "+ board[1][3] +" | "
        + board[1][4] +" | "+ board[1][5] +" | "+ board[1][6] +" | "+ board[1][7] +" |\n";
        rtn += newRow;
        rtn += "| "+ board[2][0] +" | "+ board[2][1] +" | "+ board[2][2] +" | "+ board[2][3] +" | "
        + board[2][4] +" | "+ board[2][5] +" | "+ board[2][6] +" | "+ board[2][7] +" |\n";
        rtn += newRow;
        rtn += "| "+ board[3][0] +" | "+ board[3][1] +" | "+ board[3][2] +" | "+ board[3][3] +" | "
        + board[3][4] +" | "+ board[3][5] +" | "+ board[3][6] +" | "+ board[3][7] +" |\n";
        rtn += newRow;
        rtn += "| "+ board[4][0] +" | "+ board[4][1] +" | "+ board[4][2] +" | "+ board[4][3] +" | "
        + board[4][4] +" | "+ board[4][5] +" | "+ board[4][6] +" | "+ board[4][7] +" |\n";
        rtn += newRow;
        rtn += "| "+ board[5][0] +" | "+ board[5][1] +" | "+ board[5][2] +" | "+ board[5][3] +" | "
        + board[5][4] +" | "+ board[5][5] +" | "+ board[5][6] +" | "+ board[5][7] +" |\n";
        rtn += newRow;
        rtn += "| "+ board[6][0] +" | "+ board[6][1] +" | "+ board[6][2] +" | "+ board[6][3] +" | "
        + board[6][4] +" | "+ board[6][5] +" | "+ board[6][6] +" | "+ board[6][7] +" |\n";
        rtn += newRow;
        rtn += "| "+ board[7][0] +" | "+ board[7][1] +" | "+ board[7][2] +" | "+ board[7][3] +" | "
        + board[7][4] +" | "+ board[7][5] +" | "+ board[7][6] +" | "+ board[7][7] +" |\n";
        rtn += newRow;
        System.out.print(rtn);
    }
}

So many of my methods search through the array looking for the char 'Q' using this if statement

if (board[row][col] == 'Q') {

                return false;

            } else {

                return checkRight(row, col - 1);

            }
```

however my output is always

+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

| Q | Q | Q | Q | Q | Q | Q | Q |

+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

| Q | Q | Q | Q | Q | Q | Q | Q |

+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

| Q | Q | Q | Q | Q | Q | Q | Q |

+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

| Q | Q | Q | Q | Q | Q | Q | Q |

+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

| Q | Q | Q | Q | Q | Q | Q | Q |

+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

| Q | Q | Q | Q | Q | Q | Q | Q |

+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

| Q | Q | Q | Q | Q | Q | Q | Q |

+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

| Q | Q | Q | Q | Q | Q | Q | Q |

+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

making me wonder why this statement is always answering false?

```
board[row][col] == 'Q'
```

Comment: Do not compare strings with the `==` operator, use `string1.equals(string2)`

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh You're very trigger happy.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh The OP is comparing `char`s correctly.

Comment: oh, right, my mistake. I always forget about the `char` datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your methods begins with this line:

```
if (((row < 0) || (row > 7)) || ((col > 7) || (col < 0))) {
```

And then it proceeds to check the location given by `row` and `col`.  But you've checked if you're off the board, not in the board.

Switch your `if` and `else` blocks, so that if you're off the board you immediately return `true`, else you're on the board and you can check the location for a `'Q'`.